# React login and logout implementation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, mern

I used passport local for user authentication on my backend when the user is authenticated successfully session is stored on database. In the frontend i'm using react, i can login successfully on the front end and when i checked the browser session, session is been saved but the problem if can still navigate back to login page while still the session is saved on the browser

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do i use the session to keep track of login in the front end ? even after login successfully i can still access login page and register page

Comment: How is your session stored?

Comment: Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  flash: {},
  passport: { user: '5c1d08b240b11619a57c4add' } }

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I handle my passport-local setup redirect or render statements:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loggedInUser: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchLoggedInUser();
  }

  fetchLoggedInUser = () => {
    fetchUser().then(res => {
      if (res.message) {
        this.setState({
          loggedInUser: false
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loggedInUser: true,
          user: res
        });
      }
    });
  };

  isLoggedIn = () => {
    return this.state.loggedInUser;
  };

  isAdmin = () => { // You won't have this, but it's part of my route/middleware
    console.log(this.state.user.accessLevel);
    return this.state.user.accessLevel === "Admin";
  };

  initializeLoad = () => {
    if (this.state.loggedInUser === null) {
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          // Removed a bunch of routes to shorten things up.
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            render={() =>
              // Determine if logged in // if not redirect
              // Some routes I pass in through props => <SomeView {...props} ... /> so I have access to the user.
              this.isLoggedIn() ? ( 
                <Redirect to="/profile" />
              ) : (
                <LoginView onAuthUpdate={this.handleAuthUpdate} />
              )
            }
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return this.initializeLoad();
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How do you handle logging out? Do you nest the call to the /logout route in the onClick of all logout buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand. You can check if session exists and if it does, dont show the login page but redirect to homepage.

Comment: How can check if the session on react ?